# Convergent subsequence for every sequence implies complete and totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then if every sequence contained in $X$ admits a convergent subsequence if and only if $(X,d)$ is complete and totally bounded.

I'm wondering if it would be correct to argue as follows:

**($\Rightarrow$):** Let $(x_n)_n\subset X$ be a sequence. Then it has a convergent subsequence. Thus $(X,d)$ is compact, which implies that it is complete and totally bounded.

**($\Leftarrow$):** Since $(X,d)$ is totally bounded, for every $\epsilon>0$, there are $x_1, \dots, x_n\in X$ such that $X \subset \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n \overline{B_\epsilon(x_k)}$ (where the overline indicates that that the epsilon-ball is closed). Let $(x_i)_i \subset X$ be a convergent sequence. Then there are infinitely many terms of $(x_i)_i$ in $\overline{B_\epsilon(x_k)}$ some for $k\in\{1,\dots, n\}$. Let $0<\epsilon'<\epsilon$, then there are $y_1, \dots, y_l$ such that $X \subset \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^l \overline{B_{\epsilon'}(y_k)}$, and there are infinitely many terms of $(x_n)_n$ in $\overline{B_{\epsilon'}(y_r)}\cap \overline{B_{\epsilon}(y_k)}$ for some $r\in \{1,\dots, m\}$. Proceeding inductively, we can amke $\epsilon$ smaller and smaller, and construct a sequence $(x_{i_j})_j\subset (x_i)_i$ as follows:

- Choose $i_j=1$ such that $j=s_1$ for $\min\{s_1: x_{s_1}\in \overline{B_\epsilon(x_k)}\}$
- Choose $i_j=2$ such that $j=s_2$ for $\min\{s_2: x_{s_2}\in \overline{B_\epsilon(x_k)}\cap \overline{B_\epsilon'(y_l)} \mbox{ and } s_2>s_1 \}$

$$\vdots$$

- Choose $i_j = t$ such that $j=s_t$ for $\min\{s_t: x_{s_t}\in \overline{B_\epsilon(x_k)}\cap \overline{B_\epsilon'(y_l)}\cap \dots \cap \overline{B_\epsilon^{(t)}(y_{l_t})} \mbox{ and } s_t>s_{t-1}\}$

We will then have constructed a sequence $(x_{i_j})_j$ and will have that $$\overline{B_\epsilon(x_k)}\cap \overline{B_\epsilon'(y_l)}\cap \dots \cap \overline{B_\epsilon^{(t)}(y_{l_t})}=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \overline{B_{\epsilon^{(k)}}(y_{k})}=\{x_0\}\ne \emptyset,$$

since $X$ is complete. Thus $(x_{i_j})_j$ converges to $x_0$. Hence, every sequence in $X$ admits a convergent subsequence, as required.

I'm concerned that the ($\Rightarrow$) direction is probably not quite rigorous. Would appreciate some comments.

Comment: Your forward direction looks fine to me. You could do pretty much the same thing in the reverse direction. Complete and totally bounded implies compactness, which is equivalent to sequential compactness in this case.

Comment: @RobertThingum I could've done it easier, but I was trying to do it without assuming "too much". That is, trying to use first principles.